# Pandas can't add column at index 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose, xlsxwriter

I have a Pandas dataframe that has 2 columns after transposing.  If I export to Excel, the first column comes in with formatting which cannot be controlled by xlsxwriter (all the other columns can be formatted).  If I attempt to insert a new column in the Pandas dataframe at Index 0, it comes in at Index 1.  Why is this first dataframe column unalterable in Pandas and not able to be formatted by xlsxwriter?

Here is my original code:

```
data_xls = pandas.read_excel(excelPath, "FlowTimes", index_col=None)

del data_xls['OBJECTID'] #Remove OBJECTID column
del data_xls['Shape_Length'] #Remove the Shape_Length column
data_xls.drop(data_xls.columns[0], axis =1) #Remove nameless first column

decimals = pandas.Series([0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2], index=['Length FT', 'Length MI','Flow Minutes - Mean Annual','Flow Hours - Mean Annual')
data_xls2 = data_xls.round(decimals)

data_export = data_xls2.transpose() #Transpose columns to rows
data_export.reset_index()
data_export.insert(0,"Temp", None)  #THIS IS A TESTING LINE TO SEE WHERE THE COLUMN INSERTS - IT SHOULD INSERT AS THE FIRST COLUMN AT INDEX 0

print data_export
os.remove(excelPath)

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(excelPath + "x")
data_export.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'FlowTimes', startcol = 0, startrow = 0, header=False) #header = false removes the 0 index in the first row
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['FlowTimes']
format1 = workbook.add_format()
format1.set_align('right')
format1.set_border(0)

format2 = workbook.add_format()
format2.set_bold()

worksheet.set_column("A:A", 30, format1)
worksheet.set_column("B:Z", 12, format1)
worksheet.set_row(0,None, format2)

writer.save()
```

If I don't include the data_export.insert column for testing, the output looks like this:

```
                                    0
Key Strategy Location       Location A
Length FT                         3551
Length MI                         0.67
Flow Minutes - Mean Annual          35
Flow Hours - Mean Annual          0.58
```

But if I include the data_export.insert column at index 0, it inserts after the first column like this:

```
                           Temp           0
Key Strategy Location       None  Location A
Length FT                   None        3551
Length MI                   None        0.67
Flow Minutes - Mean Annual  None          35
Flow Hours - Mean Annual    None        0.58
```

How can I either insert a new column at index 0 or control formatting of the first column while exporting with xlsxwriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that xlsxwriter imports the pandas index (row names) with formatting that cannot be altered. I worked around this by copying the index to the first column, then exporting to Excel without header or index. The xlsxwriter formatting for all columns and rows works now.  Here is the working code:

```
data_xls = pandas.read_excel(excelPath, "FlowTimes" + gdbNum, index_col=None)
del data_xls['OBJECTID'] #Remove OBJECTID column
del data_xls['Shape_Length'] #Remove the Shape_Length column
data_xls.drop(data_xls.columns[0], axis =1) #Remove nameless first column

decimals = pandas.Series([0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2], index=['Length FT', 'Length MI','Flow Minutes - Mean Annual','Flow Hours - Mean Annual')

data_export = data_xls2.transpose() #Transpose columns to rows
data_export.reset_index()
data_export.columns = data_export.iloc[0]
data_export['Key Strategy Location'] = data_export.index #adds index names (row names) as last column

cols = data_export.columns.tolist() #Create list of columns
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(-1)) #Move column with index names (row names) to be the first column
data_export = data_export[cols]

os.remove(excelPath)

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(excelPath + "x")
data_export.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'FlowTimes', startcol = 0, startrow = 0, header=False, index=False) #header = false removes index in the first row, index=false removes first column
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['FlowTimes']
format1 = workbook.add_format()
format1.set_align('right')
format1.set_border(0)

format2 = workbook.add_format()
format2.set_bold()
format2.set_align('center')

worksheet.set_column("B:Z", 20, format1)
worksheet.set_row(0,None, format2)
worksheet.set_column("A:A", 30, format1)

writer.save()
```